# Simple select query running forever

Tags: sql, sql-server

A simple SQL `Select` is query running forever for a particular ID in SQL Server 2012.

This query is running forever; it should return 10000 rows:

```
select * 
from employees 
where company_id = 34
```

If I change the query to

```
select * 
from employees 
where company_id = 12
```

it returns 7000 rows very quickly.

`Employees` is a view created by joining different tables.

Could there be a problem in the view?

Comment: Is there any different in execution plan? If so please post it.

Comment: No difference in the execution plan. Its the same table with different ID

Comment: Post the detali of the joined table(view) it will be much more simpler to determind the issue

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you have a very large table.  Such a query is probably scanning the entire tables and returning rows that match as they are encountered.

My guess is that rows for company 12 are encountered before rows for company 34.

If this is the case, then an index on `(company_id)` should help.

There may be other causes as well.  Here are two other possibilities:

- Contention for rows with company_id 34 that are causing delays on reading the data (this would depend on isolation level that you are using and the nature of concurrent updates).
- An unlimited size column which is populated with very big values for company_id 34 and empty or very small for 12.

There may be other possibilities as well.

Comment: Hi Gordan, Thank you for the explanation. I have even changed the limit to 1 but still was running forever

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can do to speed up the process is to index the column on company_id as a b-tree index would speed up the search.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the structure of the table and execution plan, here are a few things that can be suggested apart from what Gordon has already covered:

1. Could you create indexes on the underlying tables which can cover this query? That would include index on the 'searched' and 'sorted' columns (joins, where clause, order by, group by, distinct) and include the SELECTED columns in the INCLUDE part of the indexes (in case of a nonclustered rowstore index)? Aim is to see 'index seek' in the Execution Plan.
2. Update statistics on the underlying tables. (And as a side note, would suggest to keep 'AUTO CREATE' and 'AUTO UPDATE' statistics ON unless you have a reason not to do that automatically in your application)
3. Would also like to know when was the last time defragmentation was performed on the server. Long due defragmentation could be a very good reason for why you might see this kind of issues on certain values, specially on a table on which lot of write operations happen.
4. Execute the query again. Even if you do not have proper information about #3 above, you can try to execute the query skipping step#3.
5. While running the query check for waits stats in in the server by
   querying at dmvs: sys.dm_os_wait_stats and sys.dm_tran_locks. Please
   check whether the wait is due to CXPACKET (waits due to other parallel 
   processes) or PAGEIOLATCH (Reading from Disk than RAM) or locks. It
   is the starting point of the investigation which will give you the
   root cause and you can then take appropriate measure accordingly.
6. Additional quick check can be: checking 'Available RAM' in the
   server task manager. Please make sure that your SQL Server RAM is not used up by
   some other unnecessary applications/sessions.